# JBoss configuration issues

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have downloaded jboss different versions at different points. I always get configuration issues. But for the time being I am working with jboss-eap-6.1. I am able to run it as a standalone application server. I am facing following issues.

1. When I create a user for admin consol on the web, even after restart it doesn't accepts it.
2. I am unable to integrate it with Eclipse. I have all community connectors available in eclipse for all versions of JBoss. But it's not working.
3. run.bat is not working

I had another issue, I was running an older version, which i deleted, when I tried to run the .war there, it wasn't also successful.

Apache tomcat always works in all scenarios.

Please help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: you should actually provide information on these. "not working" or "doesn't accept" does not tell in any reasonable way what is happening. Take a look at instrucions on how to ask questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Your question is too broad, as it consists of three questions at least.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Jboss_Home is in correct path. Check this for more info http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/jboss-eclipse.html

Comment: i am getting following error in eclipse:  The home directory does not exist or is missing a required file or folder: modules\org\jboss\as\server\main